# Seaborn barplot and regplot create inconsistent results for Confidence Interval

Tags: python, seaborn, confidence-interval

My setup: Running Python (Python 3.9.16 64-bit) using Jupyter Notebook inside Spyder 5.3.3 on Linux Mint 21

What I do:

**First cell:** imports (Pandas, GeoPandas, seaborn, matplotlib, ...)

**Second cell:** Import a gpkg into a gdf

**Third cell:** using some parameters to create multiple new gdf with extracts from the first one. They are each saved as an entry in a df so I can automatically access them in a Loop (I later want to be able to do my analyses automatically on different sets of smaller gdf).

**Fourth cell:** writing the important bits of information from the two gdf into a df in long format. Then I create a plot with a combination of seaborn boxplot and barplot. Barplot is only used to show an errorbar on top of the boxplot using this code:

```
### add CI
ax2= sns.barplot( 
    data=df_plot, x='bez', y="distance_overtaker",
    #palette="Blues", 
    order = pos2,
    alpha=0.0,
    capsize=.1, n_boot=1000, 
    errorbar=('ci', 95),
    errcolor= 'red', #errcolor='.26' =
    errwidth=0.7, 
    ax=ax)
```

**Fith cell:** Create a different plot from the two gdf (directly, not using the df from above) using seaborn regplot:

```
for i, row in liste.iterrows():
    sns.regplot(x=krit, y='distance_overtaker', data=row['gdf'], fit_reg=True, x_jitter=0, ci=95, ax=ax, scatter_kws={'alpha':1., 's':1}, label=row['bez'])
```

When I execute the **fourth cell** the output may look like either of the following images:
[Barplot Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fKek.png)
[Barplot Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM10H.png)

You may notice that the right errorbar is different. This may or may not happen every time I execute the cell again. I could not find an regularity in it yet.

When I execute the **fith cell** the error bands look slightly different every time I execute the cell. There seem to be lots of variations. Two examples look like this:
[Regplot Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rXNK.png)
[Regplot Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbwm0.png)

Has anyone got an explanation as to why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the fluctuating results is due to the [bootstrap estimation](https://acclab.github.io/bootstrap-confidence-intervals.html) of the confidence interval. If not all samples are used, this technique will converge to the confidence interval, but will not be exact.

Further details are explained in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436412/bootstrapped-confidence-intervals-different-values-at-every-computation).

For the fourth cell with [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), increasing the value of `n_boot` will increase the stability of the value. Same goes for the fifth cell and [`sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html), just add an `n_boot` parameter and increase it beyond 1000 (at the cost of computing speed).

Another option would be to fix the seed via the `seed` parameter:

> **seed**: Seed of random number generator for reproducible bootstrapping

Comment: Thanks Christian, I thought it might be something to do with the bootstrapping, but your hints helped me to see why/how.

Comment: as with n_boot, both sns.barplot and sns.regplot accept a 'seed=n' parameter.

Comment: good point, I've overlooked that in the documentation

Comment: small correction to my last comment: I shouldn't have written `seed=n`, as a specific number of bootstrap resamples would still need to be set using `n_boot`.

Comment: but by setting the seed you will get a "reproducible bootstrapping". Fixed randomness, so to speak. I've modified my answer accordingly.